# Neo4j Cypher remove duplicates from simple query that contains ordering

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm very new to Neo4J and I can't get this simple query work.
The data I have looks like this:

```
(a)-[:likes]->(b)
(a)-[:likes]->(c)
```

Now I'd like to extract a list with everyone who likes someone else.

Tried

```
match (u)-[:likes]->(p) return u order by p.id desc;
```

This gives me a duplicate of (a).
I tried using distinct:

```
match (u)-[:likes]->(p) return distinct u order by p.id desc;
```

This gives me 'variable p undefined'.

I know that if I drop the ordering, distinct works and gives me (a) once.

But how can I work with distinct and order by in the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider why your query isn't working:

Without the distinct, you have rows with each pairing of u and p. When you use DISTINCT, how is it supposed to order when there are multiple lines for the same u, matching to multiple p's? That's an impossible task.

If you change it to order by u.id instead, then it works just fine.

I do encourage you to use labels, by the way, to restrict your query only to relevant nodes. You can also rework your query to prevent it from emitting duplicates and avoid the need for DISTINCT completely.

If we assume the nodes you're interested in are labeled with :Person, your query might be:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE EXISTS( (p)-[:likes]-() )
RETURN p ORDER BY p.id DESC
```